# Flutter Permission error in android 12 error Directory listing failed,'/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Tags: flutter, permissions, storage, android-11

i already add both permissions
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
E/flutter (25314):           `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

i want to get solution of this